# Open access peer reviewed math journals

Tags: publishing, research

I would like to have a list of existing **open access**, **peer reviewed** Mathematics journals, like the *Electronic Journal of Probability*. I have difficulties to find such a list on the Web.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Directory of Open Access Journals (DOAJ)](http://doaj.org).